# Polygonize tool error "Process gdal_polygonize.bat failed to start"

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, polygonize, bat, gdal-polygonize

I am trying to use the *Polygonize (Raster to Vector)* tool on QGIS-LTR on Windows 11.

When I launch the tool on a layer I get the following error.

```
Input parameters:
{ 'BAND' : 1, 'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS' : False, 'EXTRA' : '', 'FIELD' : 'DN', 'INPUT' : '[LAYERDIRECTORY].tif', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

GDAL command:
gdal_polygonize.bat "[LAYERDIRECTORY].tif" -b 1 -f "GPKG" C:/[…]/OUTPUT.gpkg OUTPUT DN

GDAL command result:
Process gdal_polygonize.bat failed to start. Either gdal_polygonize.bat is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to run the program
Execution failed after 0.04 seconds
```

Any clues?